# How can I combine the jQuery datepicker plugin and hover event?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, hover

I am not aware of an easy way to perform a function when hovering over a day with the jQuery UI datepicker so I am trying to do a work around by assigning a class and then calling a hover function:

```
$('.someDate').hover(function() { alert(this) } );
```

This does not work how I would like it though because it returns `[object HTML TableCellElement]`. How could I assign an attribute to each date cell `td` tag so that I can retrieve the date value through that method.

Or am i completely missing a really obvious way of doing this?

Comment: Are you trying to change the value of the cell using the datepicker? Or are you just trying to display it using the value in the cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the beforeShowDay event, which takes in the date object.

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var dateString = 'date-'+date.getDate()+'-'+date.getMonth()+'-'+date.getFullYear();  
        return [true, dateString, ''];
    }
});
```

This will add a class of `date-DD-M-YYYY` to each of the `<td>`.

The function takes a `date` as a parameter and must return an array with:

- [0] equal to true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable,
- [1] equal to a CSS class name(s) or "" for the default presentation
- [2] an optional popup tooltip for this date.

It is called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.

[Read more at jQueryUI.com](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay)

Answer (score 0):

Well I assume the tableCellElement has the date in it correct?  I haven't tested it, but..

```
alert($(this).text());
```

Comment: no because the cell itself just contains the text of the day in the month not the actual value of it.,.